# How can i create variables to get file data and insert into db those variables?

Tags: php, file

I am a newbie and have spent over 3 hours trying to find a way to get the filename, filesize, path, from the uploaded file.  But this form is doing it in a way i am not able to understand.  I need the filename, filesize, path variables stored in the db.  How can i implement a $sql insert in the code below:

```
Code:

 $upload_dir = "/var/www/anyexample/aeu"; // Directory for file storing
                                        // filesystem path


  $web_upload_dir = "/aeu"; // Directory for file storing`
                      // Web-Server dir 

 /* upload_dir is filesystem path, something like
 /var/www/htdocs/files/upload or c:/www/files/upload

    web upload dir, is the webserver path of the same
     directory. If your upload-directory accessible under 
    www.your-domain.com/files/upload/, then 
   web_upload_dir is /files/upload
   */


 // testing upload dir 
 // remove these lines if you're shure 
 // that your upload dir is really writable to PHP scripts
   $tf = $upload_dir.'/'.md5(rand()).".test";
   $f = @fopen($tf, "w");
   if ($f == false) 
    die("Fatal error! {$upload_dir} is not writable. Set 'chmod 777 {$upload_dir}'
    or something like this");
    fclose($f);
     unlink($tf);
    // end up upload dir testing 



   // FILEFRAME section of the script
   if (isset($_POST['fileframe'])) 
   {
      $result = 'ERROR';
     $result_msg = 'No FILE field found';

      if (isset($_FILES['file']))  // file was send from browser
      {
    if ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK)  // no error
    {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name']; // file name 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.'/'.$filename);
        // main action -- move uploaded file to $upload_dir 
        $result = 'OK';
    }
    elseif ($_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE)
        $result_msg = 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini';
    else 
        $result_msg = 'Unknown error';

    // you may add more error checking
    // see http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php
    // for details 
}

// outputing trivial html with javascript code 
// (return data to document)

// This is a PHP code outputing Javascript code.
// Do not be so confused ;) 
echo '<html><head><title>-</title></head><body>';
echo '<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">'."\n";
echo 'var parDoc = window.parent.document;';
// this code is outputted to IFRAME (embedded frame)
// main page is a 'parent'

if ($result == 'OK')
{
    // Simply updating status of fields and submit button
    echo 'parDoc.getElementById("upload_status").value = "file successfully uploaded";';
    echo 'parDoc.getElementById("filename").value = "'.$filename.'";';
    echo 'parDoc.getElementById("filenamei").value = "'.$filename.'";';
    echo 'parDoc.getElementById("upload_button").disabled = false;';
}
else
{
    echo 'parDoc.getElementById("upload_status").value = "ERROR: '.$result_msg.'";';
}

echo "\n".'</script></body></html>';

exit(); // do not go futher 
}
    // FILEFRAME section END



     // just userful functions
     // which 'quotes' all HTML-tags and special symbols 
     // from user input 
     function safehtml($s)
     {
      $s=str_replace("&", "&amp;", $s);
       $s=str_replace("<", "&lt;", $s);
       $s=str_replace(">", "&gt;", $s);
       $s=str_replace("'", "&apos;", $s);
       $s=str_replace("\"", "&quot;", $s);
      return $s;
     }

      if (isset($_POST['description']))
       {
         $filename = $_POST['filename'];
         $size = filesize($upload_dir.'/'.$filename);
           $date = date('r', filemtime($upload_dir.'/'.$filename));
           $description = safehtml($_POST['description']);

       // Let's generate file information page
       $html =<<<END
      <html><head><title>{$filename} [uploaded by IFRAME Async file uploader]</title></head>
        <body>
     <h1>{$filename}</h1>
   <p>This is a file information page for your uploaded file. Bookmark it, or send to anyone...   </p>
   <p>Date: {$date}</p>
   <p>Size: {$size} bytes</p>
  <p>Description: 
   <pre>{$description}</pre>
    </p>
 <p><a href="{$web_upload_dir}/{$filename}" style="font-size: large;">download file</a><br>
 <a href="{$PHP_SELF}" style="font-size: small;">back to file uploading</a><br>
<a href="{$web_upload_dir}/upload-log.html" style="font-size: small;">upload-log</a></p>
<br><br>Example by <a href="http://www.anyexample.com/">AnyExample</a>
</body></html>
 END;
// save HTML 
$f = fopen($upload_dir.'/'.$filename.'-desc.html', "w");
fwrite($f, $html);
fclose($f);
$msg = "File {$filename} uploaded, 
       <a href='{$web_upload_dir}/{$filename}-desc.html'>see file information page</a>";

// Save to file upload-log 
$f = fopen($upload_dir."/upload-log.html", "a");
fwrite($f, "<p>$msg</p>\n");
fclose($f);

// setting result message to cookie  
setcookie('msg', $msg); 
// redirecting to the script main page 
// we're doing so, to avoid POST form reposting  
// this method of outputting messages is called 'flash' in Ruby on Rails  
header("Location: http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$PHP_SELF); 
exit(); 
// redirect was send, so we're exiting now
} 


// retrieving message from cookie 
if (isset($_COOKIE['msg']) && $_COOKIE['msg'] != '')  
{  
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) 
        $msg = stripslashes($_COOKIE['msg']); 
    else
        $msg = $_COOKIE['msg'];

    // clearing cookie, we're not going to display same message several times
    setcookie('msg', ''); 
} 
?>
<!-- Beginning of main page -->
<html><head>
<title>IFRAME Async file uploader example</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
if (isset($msg)) // this is special section for outputing message 
    echo '<p style="font-weight: bold;">'.$msg.'</p>';
?> 
<h1>Upload file:</h1>
<p>File will begin to upload just after selection. </p>
<p>You may write file description, while you file is being uploaded.</p>

<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" target="upload_iframe" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="fileframe" value="true">
<!-- Target of the form is set to hidden iframe -->
<!-- From will send its post data to fileframe section of 
     this PHP script (see above) -->

<label for="file">text file uploader:</label><br>
<!-- JavaScript is called by OnChange attribute -->
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange="jsUpload(this)">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* This function is called when user selects file in file dialog */
function jsUpload(upload_field)
{
    // this is just an example of checking file extensions
    // if you do not need extension checking, remove 
    // everything down to line
    // upload_field.form.submit();

    var re_text = /\.txt|\.xml|\.zip/i;
    var filename = upload_field.value;

    /* Checking file type */
    if (filename.search(re_text) == -1)
    {
        alert("File does not have text(txt, xml, zip) extension");
        upload_field.form.reset();
        return false;
    }

    upload_field.form.submit();
    document.getElementById('upload_status').value = "uploading file...";
    upload_field.disabled = true;
    return true;
}
</script>
<iframe name="upload_iframe" style="width: 400px; height: 100px; display: none;">
</iframe>
<!-- For debugging purposes, it's often useful to remove
     "display: none" from style="" attribute -->

<br>
Upload status:<br>
<input type="text" name="upload_status" id="upload_status" 
       value="not uploaded" size="64" disabled>
<br><br>

File name:<br>
<input type="text" name="filenamei" id="filenamei" value="none" disabled>

<form action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>" method="POST">
<!-- one field is "disabled" for displaying-only. Other, hidden one is for 
    sending data -->
<input type="hidden" name="filename" id="filename">
<br><br>

<label for="photo">File description:</label><br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="50" name="description"></textarea>

<br><br>
<input type="submit" id="upload_button" value="save file" disabled>
</form>
<br><br>
<a href="<?=$web_upload_dir?>/upload-log.html">upload-log</a>
<br><br><br>

Example by <a href="http://www.anyexample.com/">AnyExample</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats a lot of code...maybe **[this answers your question](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+save+in+database)**?

Comment: @sascha thanks.  i know how to insert.  Its just i don't know how to pull the info i need from this upload script so i can insert it into my db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.'/'.$filename);
```

I would suggest adding something like the following after the previous mentioned line:

```
$size = filesize($upload_dir.'/'.$filename);
$path = $upload_dir.'/'.$filename;

mysql_connect(YOUR_HOST, YOUR_USERNAME, YOUR_PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db(YOUR_DATABASE);

mysql_query('INSERT INTO your_table SET filename=$filename, size=$size, path=$path');
```

Comment: Thanks!!! that did the trick! I do have a follow-up question.  Any idea how i can get the type of size, like kb, md? thx!

Comment: [filesize](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) returns the size in bytes.